# Complex solutions to real equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$ f(z) = \frac{z+1}{i-2z} \{ z ∈ \Bbb C,  f(z) ∈ \Bbb R \}$$

Are there any solutions other than $z = -1$?

Comment: $z=0$ is not a solution. Do you mean $z=-1$?

Comment: So, am I understanding this right if I say that you want to find all values for $z$ where $f(z) \in \mathbb R$? Then $z = 0$ is not a solution.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I meant z = -1. Meaning no complex component (b = 0, in a + bi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$f(z)=\frac{z+1}{i-2z} \tag 1$$

and asked to find the locus of points for which we have

$$\text{Im}\left(\frac{z+1}{i-2z}\right)=0$$

This is equivalent to finding the locus of points for which $(x,y)\ne (0,1/2)$ and

$$\text{Im}\left(-iz-i-2\bar z-2|z|^2\right)=0 \tag 2$$

Letting $z=x+iy$, $(2)$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y=\frac12(x+1)} \tag 3$$

$(x,y)\ne(0,1/2)$, and we are done!

To check this, substitute $(3)$ into $(1)$. Then, we have

$$f(z=x+i(x+1)/2)=\frac{x+1}{-2x}$$

which is purely real for $x\ne 0$ as expected!

Answer (score 4):

$$
w = \frac{z+1}{i-2z}
$$
$$
w(i-2z) = z+1
$$
$$
iw - 2zw = z+1
$$
$$
iw - 1 = z+2zw
$$
$$
iw-1 = z(1+2w)
$$
$$
\frac{iw-1}{1+2w} = z
$$
Now let $w$ run through $\mathbb R$ and you get lots of different values of $z$.  When $w=0$ you get $-1$.  As $w\to\infty$ you get $i/2$.  If you know a bit about the geometry of these things, you know that what you get is either a circle or a straight line that passes through those two points. (Considering straight lines to be circles of infinite radius, one can say it's always a circle.)  Since $\infty\not\in\mathbb R$, you get the whole circle except that one point $i/2$.

Miguel Atencia points out in comments that since $(w=-1/2)\mapsto (z=\infty)$, the point $\infty$ would be on this "circle".  That implies that it has to be a straight line.

Comment: Except for $w=-1/2$

Comment: To the interested reader, this is a *Möbius transformation* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), which maps *generalized circles* to generalized circles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_circle).

Comment: Why isn't it a line? If $w=-\frac12$, we get $z=\infty$. A line contains $\infty$; a circle does not. (I'm working in the Riemann sphere here.)

Comment: It appears to be much simpler I believe. It is indeed the punctured straight line; $y=\frac12 (x+1)$, $(x,y)\ne (0,1/2)$ .

Answer (score 3):

$$ f(z) = \frac{z+1}{i-2z}=\frac{(z+1)(-i-2z^*)}{(i-2z)(-i-2z^*)}=\frac{-iz-2zz^*-i-2z^*}{1+4zz^*} $$

then the denominator is a real number and you need those z for which the numerator is real thatn means you need the imaginary part of the numerator to be zero

if $z=a+bi$ then the imaginary part of the numerator is **$-a+2b-1$** you set that to zero, and all z satisfying this condition are what you are looking for!

So $z=(2b-1) +ib, b \in R$

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If you plugin $z=0$ in your first expression and your last expression you get different results.

Comment: you are right it is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: let $z=x+iy$  then $$\frac{z+1}{i-2z}=\frac{(2+i)-(i-2z)}{2(i-2z)}$$ $$=\frac{2+i}{2(i-2z)}-\frac{(i-2z)}{2(i-2z)}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2+i}{2(i-2z)}$$ $$=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2+i}{2(i-2(x+iy))}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2+i}{2(2x+i(2y-1))}$$ 
$$=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{(2+i)(2x-i(2y-1))}{2(4x^2+(2y-1)^2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Writing $z=a+b i$ and equating real and imaginary parts, you get:
$$(1+2 x) \, a = -1$$
$$(1+2 x) \, b = x$$
for some real $x$.
The parenthesis is not zero, so you can divide:
$$\frac{b}{a}=-x$$
or $b=-x a$. Substitution in the first equation results in:
$$b=\frac{x}{1+2 x}$$
$$a=\frac{-1}{1+2 x}$$
for any real number $x\ne -1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)\in \mathbb R$ iff $f(z)=\overline{f(z)}$ and doing the calculations you end up with

$2(z-\overline{z})-2i-i(z+\overline{z})=0 \Leftrightarrow 2Imz-Rez-1=0$

and thus $f$ is real on the line

$y=\frac {1}{2}(x+1)$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,1/2)$

Comment: Just like mine. ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV,  yeah. In fact i would be first if i hadn't a phone call in between:P. Really, i wonder why they come up with all th other difficult solutions for such an easy problem.

Comment: You also need to restrict the line. $(x,y)$ cannot be $(0,1/2)$.  That point is pathological.